# Russian symbols in url and route constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

There are such urls in my app:

```
local/alphabetical/service/Ю  
local/alphabetical/service/Б  
local/alphabetical/service/Ж
```

I would like to allow only symbols Ю, Б, Ж in the url

But **routes.rb**:

```
get "/alphabetical/:type/:letter" => "alpha#index",     
    :constraints => { :type => /good|service/, :letter => /[ЮБЖ]/ }, 
    :as => "alpha"
```

for `http://local/alphabetical/service/Ю` Gives me an error:

```
Routing Error  
No route matches [GET] "/alphabetical/service/%D0%AE"
```

**How to setup a constraint in routes.rb file to allow only Ю, Б, Ж symbols?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to handle the unescaping of those characters yourself. Have a look at this example here: [Redirect when using I18n with Rails is encoding the forward slash as %2F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419006/redirect-when-using-i18n-with-rails-is-encoding-the-forward-slash-as-2f/11419264#11419264)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @phoet for reply, its very useful.
Will someone interesting...

For my case the solution is:

**Product** model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    LETTERS = %w( А Б В Г Ґ Д Е Є Ж З І Ї Й К Л М Н О П Р С Т У Ф Х Ц Ч Ш Щ Ю Я )
end
```

**routes.rb**:

```
get "/alphabetical/:type/:letter" => "alpha#index",     
        :constraints => lambda { |req| req.params[:type] =~ /good|service/ and req.params[:letter] =~ /[#{Product::LETTERS.join}]/i }, 
        :as => "alpha"
```

Answer (score 2):

had a similar issue, post for the sake of an example.

```
resources :listings, path: "объявления" do
  get ":kind(/:category(/:subcategory(/:state(/:city))))",
      constraints: lambda { |req| %w(работа недвижимость услуги продажи).include? req.params[:kind] },
      to: "listings#search",
      as: "search",
      on: :collection
  end
```